# react setState doesn't work with stream data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB to sync my remote db with my localdb, below code is placed in componentDidMount

```
const that = this
var localDB = new PouchDB('localdb')
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://192.168.1.106:5984/remotedb')

localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
    live: true,
    retry: true
}).on('change', function (change) {
    console.log('test')
    that.setState({
      items: [this.state.items, ...change.change.docs]
    })
})
```

I have no clue why it doesn't do anything at all

Comment: Add the response data to the description for better understanding. Also you are using this.state.items in the setState method, you should be using that.state.items as you have defined it above

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems there:

1. You've used `this` instead of `that` in the change callback. It's almost certainly doing something: Writing an error the console. (Rather than the `that` pattern, just use an arrow function so you can use this.)
2. You're breaking one of the fundamental rules of React: If you'e setting state based on existing state (which you are, you're using `this.state.items` as part of the new state), you **must** use the callback version of setState ([more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).
3. You almost certainly wanted to spread `this.state.items` rather than including that array as your first element in the new array. (I don't know whether you also wanted to spread `change.change.docs`.)

Fixing all three:

```
localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
    live: true,
    retry: true
}).on('change', change => {
    this.setState(({items}) => ({items: [...items, /*...*/change.change.docs]}));
})
```

(The `/*...*/` is: Use `...` there if you really want to spread `change.change.docs`, or remove it if you don't.)

That uses an arrow function so you don't need the `that` variable, and uses the callback version of `setState` with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the parameter list to grab the `items` state member and create a new `items` member with `change.change.docs` appended.

We could use destructuring in the parameter list of the `change` callback as well:

```
localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
    live: true,
    retry: true
}).on('change', ({change: {docs}}) => {
    this.setState(({items}) => ({items: [...items, /*...*/docs]}));
})
```